# FixedColumns DataTables misaligned and duplicate each row in one columns

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables, adminlte

I'm having problem with FixedColumns DataTables. As you can see from the picture, the columns duplicate all the rows and misaligned it. I'm not sure what is wrong, but I'm already using the reference from DataTables websites and still not working, can you help me?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After awhile, i solved the problem. Because i'm using DataTables bs4, i need to add the CSS. And than the FixedColumn was fixed. Link to CSS Extensions :

> https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html